# Kendo UI + Cordova. Orientation issue.

Tags: cordova, mobile, kendo-ui, screen-orientation, telerik-appbuilder

I'm working on HTML5\JS application with Kendo UI (Appbuilder, cordova).
And here is the issue: 
how can I manually set orientation (landscape\portrait). 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make your app *always* only display in one orientation, or do you mean that you want to force the orientation to one or the other at any time even if the device isn't rotated that way?

Comment: I want my app always display in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

In AppBuilder, in the Properties -> General section, you can choose the supported device orientations. Just uncheck "portrait" and your app will only run in landscape mode.

Comment: How can I do this via configuration or within source code?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to just toggle the setting in AppBuilder as Rob answered, you coudl edit it in the [Cordova config.xml file](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/config_ref_index.md.html):

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

This Javascript might work ([taken from here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/xw7QSJVCf5I)):

```
function shouldRotateToOrientation(interfaceOrientation) {
    return (3 === interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Otherwise, see these possible duplicates:

[Cordova iOS Change Screen Orientation To Landscape on a Single Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286177/cordova-ios-change-screen-orientation-to-landscape-on-a-single-page)

[Cordova 3.x forcing screen orientation at run-time IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607226/cordova-3-x-forcing-screen-orientation-at-run-time-ios)